# How to fix shape keys after having used symmetrize on the basis shape key?

Tags: shape-keys

I used "symmetrize" on the basis key because at some point I lost symmetry. It messed up all the other shape keys. I thought when you select a full model and click symmetrize it would just restore symmetry but it seems like it duplicates half of the mesh and mirrors it, not sure. I had tried snap to symmetry first but it didn't give me good results. Am I screwed? I saved after symmetrizing, I can't undo.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19296/can-i-fix-broken-shape-keys-after-editing-basis/19297#19297

Comment: If it made duplicate geometry, can't you select that new geometry, delete it, and be back where you started before symmetrizing? And as for creating symmetry, wouldn't a Mirror Modifier be the way to go? I can't see your project, so I don't know if this is practical to do, but based on your description this is what I imagine could *possibly* work.

Comment: I already had applied the mirror modifier at some point. I had been working with X-Mirror on for while without the mirror modifier. It was a full model, not half. Blender just always seems to lose symmetry at some point. I didn't notice until later so I used symmetrize but apparently this deletes half of your model, duplicates the other half and mirrors it. I thought it just moved the vertices.

Comment: Have no idea if you found help so far. Maybe try some of these suggestions? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90859/possible-to-fix-a-broken-shape-key-with-a-copy-of-the-model/90911?noredirect=1#comment160397_90911 only works if you got an auto save from the model. Otherwise you have to re-create the shape keys I guess.

Comment: I have tried the method, It works and fixes the problem with the symmetry. However, if you have shapes that influence left and right while not being symmetrical. For example, a jow left (or right) is a problem. But even with this problem, as it rebuilds the symmetry perfectly it still saves the day. You have to fix some blendshapes, though. But as the symmetry will work after the process, it still a great way! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think it's the same that I just solve.
I had my character with mirror applied and shape keys. I tried to apply the mirror but I cant, so

- The first thing I did is save with another name.
- In the new file I deleted half of my character, leaving the very middle vertex.
- In shape key I rename some "Worry" to "WorryL", "Frown" to "FrownL", etc.
- In object mode you duplicate my character and made a scale X -1.
- In the new object shape keys rename the renamed ones. "WorryL" to "WorryR", etc
- Then I put it in the right position and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to join. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to fix normals
- <kbd>W</kbd> and *Remove Doubles*.

Ready. 
I have My character With some shapeKeys for Left and Right. Others like Phonemes I leave the like the was.

Comment: There definitely should be a button somewhere for this procedure in the future versions, as it works perfect.