# Shape Keys: Why did it do this?

Tags: shape-keys

So I made some shape keys for the lips, added some eyebrows and went to work on them, only to notice that they're being affected by the lip shape keys. 
[image]
How do I fix this? Do I have to make the eyebrows before adding these shape keys to the face? Also why and how are they affecting the eyebrows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shape keys are for when the modeling is done. Don't start adding shape keys and then expect to be able to add verts, edges or faces later. You *may* still move verts around a little, but results are sometimes unpredictable.

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?303554-Editing-the-Basis-shape-key-after-making-shapekeys

[Can I fix broken shape keys after editing basis?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19296/can-i-fix-broken-shape-keys-after-editing-basis)